# Show that $z=0$ is a pole for $f(z)$ and find the order of the pole

Tags: complex-analysis

> Show that $z=0$ is a pole for $$f(z) = \frac {\sin z}{e^{\tan z} - e^{\sin z}}$$
>   and find the order of the pole.

$\lim_{z\to 0} \sin z = 0$, and $\lim_{z\to0} e^{\tan z} - e^{\sin z} = 0$ , so we can apply l'hopital's rule
$$\frac {\cos ^3 z}{e^{\tan z} - e^{\sin z} \cos^3z}$$ which diverges to infinity.

So $\lim_{z\to0}f(z) = \infty$, which means it has a pole at $z=0$.

Now i stacked in second part, in finding order.

I know that it is enough to find zero order of $\frac 1{f(z)}$ function, but it doesn't helped me much.

Any help or advice is appreciated.

Comment: Can you work out the order of the zero at $z=0$ for the numerator and denominator of $f$?

Comment: Yes I got it, but in denominator i always get some power for $\sin z$ , and that is the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numerator
$$
\sin z=z\,f(z), \quad \text{with $f(0)\ne 0$.}
$$
Denominator
$$
g(z)=e^{\tan z}-e^{\sin z}
$$
with $g(0)=0$, 
$$
g'(z)=e^{\tan z}\sec^2 z-e^{\sin z}\cos z, \quad \text{and $g'(0)=0$,}
$$
$$
g''(z)=e^{\tan z}\sec^4 z+2e^{\tan z}\sec^3z\sin  z-e^{\sin z}\cos^2 z+2e^{\sin z}\sin z
$$
and $g''(0)=0$.

Finally
$$
g'''(z)=8e^{\tan z}\sec^6 z+7e^{\tan z}\sec^5z\sin  z-e^{\sin z}\cos^4 z+2e^{\sin z}\sin z\cos z+2e^{\sin z}\sin z\cos^2 z+2e^{\sin z}\cos z
$$
and hence $g'''(0)=9\ne 0.$ Hence $g(z)=z^3h(z)$, with $h(0)\ne 0$.

Thus 
$$
\frac{\sin z}{e^{\tan z}-e^{\sin z}}=\frac{zf(z)}{z^3h(z)}=\frac{w(z)}{z^2},
$$
where $w(0)\ne 0$.

Hence second order pole.

Answer (score 0):

Using Taylor series built at $z=0$ and composition of them

$$\sin(z)=z-\frac{z^3}{6}+\frac{z^5}{120}+O\left(z^7\right)$$
$$e^{\sin(z)}=1+z+\frac{z^2}{2}-\frac{z^4}{8}-\frac{z^5}{15}-\frac{z^6}{240}+O\left(z^7\right)$$
$$\tan(z)=z+\frac{z^3}{3}+\frac{2 z^5}{15}+O\left(z^7\right)$$
$$e^{\tan(z)}=1+z+\frac{z^2}{2}+\frac{z^3}{2}+\frac{3 z^4}{8}+\frac{37 z^5}{120}+\frac{59
   z^6}{240}+O\left(z^7\right)$$
$$e^{\tan(z)}-e^{\sin(z)}=\frac{z^3}{2}+\frac{z^4}{2}+\frac{3 z^5}{8}+\frac{z^6}{4}+O\left(z^7\right)$$
$$f(z) = \frac {\sin (z)}{e^{\tan (z)} - e^{\sin (z)}}=\frac{z-\frac{z^3}{6}+\frac{z^5}{120}+O\left(z^7\right) } {\frac{z^3}{2}+\frac{z^4}{2}+\frac{3 z^5}{8}+\frac{z^6}{4}+O\left(z^7\right) }=\frac{2}{z^2}-\frac{2}{z}+\frac{1}{6}+\frac{z}{3}+O\left(z^2\right)$$